# Converting binary data to an image

Tags: java, image, http, binary

I have a problem and I hope you can help me. The problem is the following. I have a camera that has an http service, and I am communicating with the camera using the http. So  I send http request and I receive  an http response in which I have a binary jpeg data. But I do not know how to convert that data into picture. So my question, and my main problem is how can I convert that binary data into picture.

This is my code so far, I am stuck in getting the image.

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.10.1.154" + GETIMAGESCR());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine;
// while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
// inputLine = in.readLine();
File file = new File("D:\\alphas\\proba.bin");
boolean postoi = file.createNewFile();
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D:\\alphas\\proba.bin");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
out.write(in.readLine());
// out.close();
// System.out.println("File created successfully.");
System.out.println(inputLine);
}
System.out.println("File created successfully.");
out.close();
in.close()
```

;

Comment: I'd recommend using some kind of jpeg library. Doing it yourself can be a bit of work. But unless you specify some sort of programming language you want to do that with, I don't think I can be more concrete. Assuming you are looking for programming solution.

Comment: I am working in java. I have menage to write a code that helps me receive the banary jpeg data and I menage so save that binary data in a file, I just don't know how to convert that binary data into an image, using java.

Comment: You should then add the java tag. Btw those bytes are technically a picture/image in a raw form (compressed with jpeg). Sort of. What exactly do you want to do it them? Save them to a file?

Comment: I don't need to save it like raw, we need to create the picture and to save the picture like jpeg. It is not necessary to have the raw data, I just need to get and save the picture, but I don't know how to get the picture

Comment: Just save it as you would normally save data into a file. If it is compressed as jpeg you would have jpeg file.

Comment: I tried to save it like  file.jpeg, but it's not working. In the question above I show you my code so far, how I am saving the file etc. I just don't know how to get the image.

Comment: You don't want to read binary data (like an image) with a `Reader`.  You want to use `InputStream` and `OutputStream` directly.  Using a `Reader` will do character encoding conversions on your data which will corrupt it.

Comment: Aham, thanks a lot. I am quite new n java, so it's the first time I am working with images in java, so if you could just tell me how to read binary data with InputStream and OutputStream directly???

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.10.1.154" + GETIMAGESCR());
InputStream is = new InputStream(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\alphas\\proba.jpg");
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int readBytes = 0;
while ((readBytes = is.read(data)) > 0) {
  out.write(data,0,readBytes);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
is.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am quite new in java, so it's a first time I am working with images, so I would appreciate if you could help me a little bit more, with an example maybe, how to fix this, and how not to use reader but to use inputstream directly and to save the picture like jpeg. Thanks in forward.

Comment: MY question exactly is how to save all of it and not use reader?

Comment: Thank you very very very much!!!! I'll definitely try this I'll tell you if it's working properly. Thanks again for all of your effort. Greeting

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it does what you expect it to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use javax.imageio.ImageIO

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.10.1.154" + GETIMAGESCR());
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url.openStream())
```